# How do I change hostname in trueos

Tags: hostname, trueos

I want to change the hostname that was generated during installation. How do I do that in Trueos?

Answer (score 0):

Modify `/etc/rc.conf` and add or change the variable `hostname` therein:

```
hostname="myveryownhostname"
```

I believe this is documented in the manual for the `hostname` utility.

If the variable is not there, the hostname of the system will be `Amnesiac`.

The variable is also documented in the `rc.conf` manual:

> `hostname`
>
> (str) The fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of this host on
>            the network.  This should almost certainly be set to something meaningful, even    if there is no network connection.  If
>            `dhclient(8)` is   used to set the hostname via DHCP, this variable should be  set to an empty string.  If this value remains
>            unset when the system is done booting your console login will
>            display the default hostname of `Amnesiac`.

Comment: On PC-BSD one can also change it from the "Advanced" tab of the Network Configuration manager on the PC-BSD Control Panel.  I'd have to check whether this is the same for TrueOS.